# Сравнить два цвета RGB и определить, похожи ли они

Tags: c#, алгоритм, unity3d, color

Нужно сгенерировать 3 цвета, т.е. что бы один не был похож на другой, но нужно максимальное кол-во цветов, т.е.

`new Color(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,1f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,1f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,1f))`

создаст произвольный цвет, а как потом проверить не похож ли он (оператор == точно не подойдет) на другой цвет, всегда получается что немного похож и становиться трудно различить на скорости т.е. быстро меняются и нужно определить где какой.

И еще, задавать разные значения для трёх цветов не пойдет, т.к. красные может быть любым из трёх, т.е. что бы шанс того что один цвет будет первый точно такой же как и второй и третий.

**Суть**: Мне нужен метод, который вернет булевую переменную после вопроса похож ли цвет1 на цвет2.

Comment: что в вашем понимании похож?

Comment: @SeeSharp, в этом, как бы, и состоит суть вопроса :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Вообще говоря, цвет можно представить в виде обычных координат в трехмерном пространстве. Можно посчитать расстояние между двумя интересующими цветами и с определенной *дельтой* получить ответ на вопрос "А похож ли цвет1 на цвет2?".

А расcчитать длину такого вектора достаточно просто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть одна **большая проблема**, RGB - это линейное пространство, которое еще и все 3 цвета распределяет равномерно, когда человеческий глаз не настолько равномерно реагирует на цвета... в общем, тема эта глубокая и не особо поможет решить вопрос, если заинтересовались - гуглите **CIELAB vs sRGB**.

---

### Как получить более хорошую метрику для сравнения цветов?

Ответ прост в своей формулировке - перейти в другое, более "полноценное" цветовое пространство, например CIELAB. Еще для этих целей, насколько я знаю, применяют LUV, не особо с ним знаком, так что не могу их сравнить.

Но и тут есть небольшая проблема, из Linear RGB нельзя перейти в LAB, нужно промежуточное преобразование в XYZ, с него и начнем.

---

### Linear RGB -> sRGB -> XYZ

Стоит начать с того, что цвет, используемый в Unity - Linear RGB, а не sRGB. Чтобы это исправить, нужно открыть почти что любую ссылку по пространству RGB и найти преобразование:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интерпретировать это на языке проще легкого:

```
private static float LinearToSRGB(float channel) {
    if (channel > 0.0031308f) {
        channel = 1.055f * Mathf.Pow(channel, 1 / 2.4f) - 0.055f;
    }
    else {
        channel *= 12.92f;
    }
    return channel;
}

public static Color LinearToSRGB(Color col) {
    return 
        new Color(
            LinearToSRGB(col.r),
            LinearToSRGB(col.g),
            LinearToSRGB(col.b)
        );
}
```

---

Также стоит учитывать, в каком цветовом пространстве был задан изначальный цвет. Может, вы изначально задали sRGB или вообще gamma-corrected RGB. Для первого случая преобразование вообще не требуется, а для преобразования gamma -> sRGB вы легко найдете формулу в интернете.

---

Теперь, наконец, можно приступать к преобразованию **sRGB -> XYZ**:

Все, что требуется - перемножить матрицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где [М] - специальная матрица значений, [которую давно за нас определили](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_to_XYZ.html). Нам понадобятся 2 матрицы: для D50 и D65 соответственно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут стоит немного остановиться и разобраться, что такое D50 и D65. На русский довольно сложно перевести, но я все же попытаюсь: это в своем роде точка белого и вообще самый яркий цвет в цветовом пространстве - белый, разумеется. Ну и вокруг этих точек построили целые стандарты, алгоритмы, а точнее константы, которых нам и нужны.

Для последующей настройки введем enum:

```
public enum Illuminant {
    D50,
    D65
}
```

**Для чего нам оба стандарта?**

D50 хоть и постарше, чем D65, но его все еще используют, насколько я знаю.

---

Чтобы лишний раз не запутаться - создадим отдельный класс для цвета в пространстве XYZ:

```
public class XYZ {
    // точки самого яркого цвета - белого в обоих стандартах
    private static readonly Vector3 D50 = new Vector3(0.966797f, 1.0f, 0.825188f);
    private static readonly Vector3 D65 = new Vector3(0.95047f, 1.0f, 1.0883f);

    // цветовые компоненты
    public float x { get; set; }
    public float y { get; set; }
    public float z { get; set; }

    // конструктор от обычного цвета из Unity
    public XYZ(Color col, ColorUtility.Illuminant illuminant = ColorUtility.Illuminant.D65) {
        // первым делом переводим цвет из linear RGB в sRGB с помощью
        // метода, описанного выше
        col = LinearToSRGB(col);

        float r = col.r;
        float g = col.g;
        float b = col.b;

        // в зависимости от стандарта выбираем матрицу и самую яркую точку
        // перемножаем матрицы "вручную", как было описано выше
        // после чего нормализуем значения всех компонент цвета
        switch (illuminant) {
            case ColorUtility.Illuminant.D50:
                // sRGB -> XYZ
                x = 0.4360747f * r + 0.3850649f * g + 0.1430804f * b;
                y = 0.2225045f * r + 0.7168786f * g + 0.0606169f * b;
                z = 0.0139322f * r + 0.0971045f * g + 0.7141733f * b;

                float D50x = D50.x;
                float D50y = D50.y;
                float D50z = D50.z;

                // Clamping to D50 white point & normalizing them afterwards
                x = Mathf.Clamp(x, 0f, D50x) / D50x;
                y = Mathf.Clamp(y, 0f, D50y) / D50y;
                z = Mathf.Clamp(z, 0f, D50z) / D50z;
                break;
            case ColorUtility.Illuminant.D65:
                // sRGB -> XYZ
                x = 0.4124564f * r + 0.3575761f * g + 0.1804375f * b;
                y = 0.2126729f * r + 0.7151522f * g + 0.0721750f * b;
                z = 0.0193339f * r + 0.1191920f * g + 0.9503041f * b;

                float D65x = D65.x;
                float D65y = D65.y;
                float D65z = D65.z;

                // Clamping to D65 white point & normalizing them afterwards
                x = Mathf.Clamp(x, 0f, D65x) / D65x;
                y = Mathf.Clamp(y, 0f, D65y) / D65y;
                z = Mathf.Clamp(z, 0f, D65z) / D65z;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### XYZ -> LAB

Формула получения LAB цвета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сами функции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И константы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Опять же, 1в1 переносим в код и получаем следующее:

```
public class LAB {
    private const float e = 0.008856f;
    private const float k = 903.3f;

    public float l { get; set; }
    public float a { get; set; }
    public float b { get; set; }

    public LAB(Color col, ColorUtility.Illuminant illuminant = ColorUtility.Illuminant.D65) {
        Vector3 lab = XYZtoLAB(new XYZ(col, illuminant));
        l = lab.x;
        a = lab.y;
        b = lab.z;
    }
    public LAB(XYZ col) {
        Vector3 lab = XYZtoLAB(col);
        l = lab.x;
        a = lab.y;
        b = lab.z;
    }

    // эта функция и есть нужная нам метрика, но об этом позже
    public float DeltaE(LAB color) {
        return Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow((this.l - color.l), 2f) + Mathf.Pow((this.a - color.a), 2f) + Mathf.Pow((this.b - color.b), 2f));
    }

    private static float ApplyLABconversion(float value) {
        if (value > e) {
            value = Mathf.Pow(value, 1.0f / 3.0f);
        }
        else {
            value = (k * value + 16) / 116;
        }
        return value;
    }

    private static Vector3 XYZtoLAB(XYZ col) {
        float x = col.x;
        float y = col.y;
        float z = col.z;

        float fx = ApplyLABconversion(x);
        float fy = ApplyLABconversion(y);
        float fz = ApplyLABconversion(z);

        return new Vector3(
                 116.0f * fy - 16.0f,
                 500.0f * (fx - fy),
                 200.0f * (fy - fz)
             );
    }
}
```

---

### Так как же сравнивать 2 цвета на похожесть?

Вспоминаем самую первую формулу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И применяем ее к LAB цвету, а не к обычному sRGB:

```
public float DeltaE(LAB color) {
        return Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow((this.l - color.l), 2f) + Mathf.Pow((this.a - color.a), 2f) + Mathf.Pow((this.b - color.b), 2f));
}
```

Все, что теперь остается сделать - проверить, входит ли дельта в заданные рамки:

```
public static bool AreSimilar(Color color1, Color color2, float delta, Illuminant illuminant = Illuminant.D65) {
    return (new LAB(color1, illuminant)).DeltaE(new LAB(color2, illuminant)) <= delta;
}
```

Чем больше delta, тем проще будет "подобрать" похожие цвета, чем, соответственно, меньше дельта, тем сложнее "подобрать" похожие цвета.

Для черного и белого, к примеру, такая дельта будет равна 100. Это обусловлено тем, что они находятся на противоположных краях этого цветового пространства. Если, опять же, интересно копнуть поглубже - стоит почитать умные статьи, я явно лучше них не объясню :)